# Looping through html with beautiful soup in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to loop through a html table.

On the page I'm looking through there is only one table. So that's easy to locate. Under that there are several `<tr>`s, and I want to look through these apart from some headers defined by `<th>` instead of `<td>`s. Each `<tr>` consists of several different classed in the `<td>`s. I'm only looking to collect the two `<td>`'s with class="table-name" and the `<td>` with the class="table-score".

I have tried to work with:

```
rows = html.find("table", class_="table").find_all("tr")

for row in rows:
    if row.find("th") is None:
        td_names = row.findall("td")

for td_name in td_names:
    print(td_name)
```

But I'm really having any success with that.

So basically the html looks something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-rank">1</td>
    <td class="table-name">John</td>
    <td class="table-name">Jim</td>
    <td class="table-place">Russia</td>
    <td class="table-score">2-1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm only looking for "John", "Jim", "2-1".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first you code is not indented ,then can you show the error you're getting ?

Comment: The thing is I'm not really getting a relevant result. My issue is that the table-name is present twice, so I can't just loop through the tr looking for the class name I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all) will return a list of all elements matching the filter. You can use index of the list to choose the element you need. 0 for first, 1 for second etc.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<table>
<tr>
<th>Header</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="table-rank">1</td>
<td class="table-name">John</td>
<td class="table-name">Jim</td>
<td class="table-place">Russia</td>
<td class="table-score">2-1</td>
</tr>
</table>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
our_tr=soup.find('table').find_all('tr')[1] #the second tr in the table - index starts at 0
#print all td's of seconf tr
our_tds=our_tr.find_all('td')
print(our_tds[1].text)
print(our_tds[2].text)
print(our_tds[4].text)
```

Output

```
John
Jim
2-1
```

Comment: This solution assumes the cells of the desired classes are always in the same place, though. It ignores the classes and just gets whatever is in the second, third, and fifth cells.

Comment: @BillM. Every solution has to assume certain things. Are you not assuming that the names of the classes won't change next time you send a request? If something breaks we can come again and fix the indices.

Comment: The OP explicitly said he's looking to collect cells of those specified classes, not necessarily the ones in those numerical positions. Arguing that these might be dynamically-generated class names doesn't change that.

Answer (score -1):

In your specific example, `.find("table", class_="table")` won't return anything, because it's looking for a table with a class name of "table".  Your `<table>` tag here is just `<table>`, not `<table class="table">`.

I did the following, and I was able to extract the items for the classes you wanted.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-rank">1</td>
    <td class="table-name">John</td>
    <td class="table-name">Jim</td>
    <td class="table-place">Russia</td>
    <td class="table-score">2-1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
t = soup.find('table')

td_data = []

for row in t.find_all('tr'):
    # Ignore any rows containing a <th> cell.
    if not row.th:
        # Generate a list of any strings found inside <td class="table-name"> tags.
        # Concatenate this list with td_data.  Do the same with cells of the class "table-score".
        td_data += [ s.string for s in row.find_all('td', class_="table-name") ]
        td_data += [ s.string for s in row.find_all('td', class_="table-score") ]

print(td_data)
```

The reason I declared `td_data` as an empty list and then just added the new lists to it, is so that you can run this algorithm for tables where you have multiple rows that may have what you're looking for.  Also, there are some ways you could do an "or" search of sorts to find  tags with either of the classes you want, but since there are only two of them, I figured it was simple enough to gather the full list of table-name values and table-score values.  If one of these turns out to be empty, then td_data is unchanged.

Answer (score -1):

If I see the table tag, I usually let pandas do the work and you can filter out the columns you don't need or want.

```
html = """
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-rank">1</td>
    <td class="table-name">John</td>
    <td class="table-name">Jim</td>
    <td class="table-place">Russia</td>
    <td class="table-score">2-1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
"""

import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_html(html, skiprows=1)
results = df[0]
```

EDIT:
If you are more concerned about the actual class attributes though, I can offer 2 alternatives.

**Option: 1**

Still use pandas to parse the table, but prior to, use BeautifulSoup to eliminate the unwanted columns/tags/class (whatever you'd like to call them) with `.decompose()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4

html = """
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-rank">1</td>
    <td class="table-name">John</td>
    <td class="table-name">Jim</td>
    <td class="table-place">Russia</td>
    <td class="table-score">2-1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

keep_list = ["table-name", "table-score"]

for data in soup.find_all('td'):
    class_attr = data['class'][0]
    if class_attr in keep_list:
        continue
    else:
        soup.select("td."+class_attr)[0].decompose()

df = pd.read_html(str(soup), skiprows=1)
results = df[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
      0    1    2
0  John  Jim  2-1
```

**Option: 2**

Similar to the other solutions, just find specific class attributes.

```
import bs4

html = """
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="table-rank">1</td>
    <td class="table-name">John</td>
    <td class="table-name">Jim</td>
    <td class="table-place">Russia</td>
    <td class="table-score">2-1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

keep_list = ["table-name", "table-score"]
alpha = soup.find_all('td', class_=lambda x: x in keep_list)

for data in alpha:
    print (data.text)

# or if wanted in list
results = [ data.text for data in alpha ]
```

**Output:**

```
John
Jim
2-1
```

Alternatively, the list can be done in 3 lines:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

keep_list = ["table-name", "table-score"]

results = [ data.text for data in soup.find_all('td', class_=lambda x: x in keep_list)]
```

**Output:**

```
print (results)
['John', 'Jim', '2-1']
```

Comment: How would you then extract the cell contents of the desired classes, though?

Comment: You can manipulate the dataframe, by just selecting the columns you need.

Comment: Yes, I know you could then get the strings by `df[0][1][1]`, `df[0][2][1]`, `df[0][4][1]`, but this assumes you know which columns you want by their actual column number.  The OP explicitly said he wants to get cells based on the class of their <td> tags.  How would you know the cells with the classes you want are always in the same place for every table?

Comment: It's just an alternate solution that they may or may not feel is useful. I'm simply pointing out a use of `.read_html()` can be used to parse. They also state its for ONE table with several rows. unless the table has different number of columns for different rows, I'm assuming the structure of this table is multiple rows following that pattern and. Yes he's looking for a class, but high level, he's really just trying to get specific columns from the one table. But you are correct, and to your point, this may not be for every table he/she encounters, so I adjusted my solution.